# Default printer in KDE 4 printer dialogs

Tags: kde, printing, cups

How can I configure CUPS and/or KDE so that my printer is the default when I hit print in any KDE application (as opposed to the PDF printer)? It is set as default in CUPS, but that seems to have no impact on KDE.

Answer (score 2):

Removing `/home/$USER/.cups/lpoptions` did the job - it contained a line setting default printer to PDF for my user. No idea how this file got there.

Answer (score 0):

Set a new default printer with:

```
lpoptions -d PRINTER
```

See http://www.lbl.gov/IT/CIS/dp/cups-lpoptions.html for more information.